# How to format date to UK date in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel, formatting, userform

I have created a userform which looks at several cells inputting dates. Strange that it is very temperamental when it formats the date as UK format. When I initially written the code it would format the date in UK format, and then again the next, today however the 11th September 2017 it has diverted to a US Format and instead of reading `11/09/2017` it is reading `09/11/2017`.

The dates are put in via a textbox and coded as below. Can someone issue any advice to prevent this happening in the future? Also the language and keyboard setups are both English U.K.

```
ws.Cells(mRow, 2).Value = Format(Date, "DD/MM/YYYY")
ws.Cells(mRow, 12).Value = Format(Me.TxtRcD.Value, "DD/MM/YYYY")
ws.Cells(mRow, 18).Value = Format(Me.TxtDD.Value, "DD/MM/YYYY")
```

In all of these examples the date has been input in the textbox as 11/09/2017

Comment: Just a comment: I found these differences always confusing and never managed to get them right (no one knows which one is right after a while). Therefore we decided to use the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date format `YYYY-MM-DD` **everywhere**. Because it is the only one that can not be misunderstood by humans too. We just switched Windows properties to that format (by group policy on every PC). Maybe that is worth for you to think about.

Comment: @Peh Yes thank you that works perfectly. Much appreciated for the information. Makes perfect sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are reading the cell as correct data format - that might cause problems when formatting. If it is String, convert it to Number or Date.
If you are reading it as number, NumberFormat might be useful:

```
selection.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
```

Also, pay attention to uppercase and lowercase: DD is not the same as dd. Don't have it on top of my head, but for example if you need month as 3 first letters (like FEB, JUN, etc.) you need 'MMM' not 'mmm'